# Goutte login with ID

Tags: javascript, php, goutte

I want to ask about Goutte. I'm using this goutte https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte and implement it into Codeigniter. And now I am trying to do scraping.

When I want to develop it, the link that I want to login code is like this

```
<div class="loginOperationContent">
    <form id="login-form">
        <div class="loginIdArea">
            <label class="textareaWrap"><span class="formText">Login ID</span><input id="loginId" name="" type="text" /></label>
        </div>
        <div class="loginPassArea">
            <label class="textareaWrap"><span class="formText">Password</span><input id="password" name="" type="password" /></label>
        </div>
    </form>

    <div class="loginBtnArea">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btnLogin">
            <span class="btnInner">
                <input type="hidden" id="windowId" value="LxI2eRwmN1094O8CYV5T">
                <span class="btnText" id="login_btn">Submit</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This form is not a common form, name="" is empty and the submit button is using JS. And here is my scraping code in controller:

```
      $client = new Client();
      $crawler = $client->request('GET', '<link login>');
      $crawler = $client->click($button = $crawler->selectButton('Submit')->form());
      $loginForm = $crawler->filter('form#login-form')->form();
      $loginForm['#loginId'] = '<login ID>';
      $loginForm['#password'] = '<password>';
      $crawler = $client->submit($loginForm);
      $crawler->filter('.userInfoName')->each(function ($node) {
          d($node->text());
      });
```

But it doesn't work. Please help me.

Comment: do everyone know how to solve this?